# Install fail in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the website 'http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu'

But when i run `sudo apt-get update`, the result is:

```
Hit:1 http://mirrors.sankuai.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.sankuai.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.sankuai.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirrors.sankuai.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:5 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ros/ubuntu xenial Release
Reading package lists... Done
```

I run `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-base`, I got the result like this:

```
root@walle-dev:~# sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-ros-base : Depends: ros-kinetic-actionlib but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: ros-kinetic-bond-core but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: ros-kinetic-dynamic-reconfigure but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: ros-kinetic-nodelet-core but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: ros-kinetic-pluginlib but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: ros-kinetic-ros-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270465/install-fail-in-ubuntu-16.04/) by [Dragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30020/dragon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2017-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my fault. I change the apt source and this lead to this problem.

---

Originally posted by [Dragon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30020/dragon/) with karma: 68 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qinsheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/32001/qinsheng/) on 2017-09-23**:
I meet with the same questio, can you help me?